# problem with 'QueryDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, data-structures, django-rest-framework

```
class PreUpdateDeleteAPIView(APIView):
serializer_class = PreEditSerializer
queryset = Reserve.objects.all()
def post(self, request):
    code = request.data()
   
   
    """''.join(code)"""
    data = {
        reverse('update-delete', args = [code] ,request=request)
    }
    return Response(data)
```

hello. i have an problem for converting querydict to string. what should i do now?
i have tried json.dump and several answers in SOF. but i didnt get my answer yet!

Answer (score 1):

`request.data` is a property that returns a `QueryDict`, so you work with:

```
code = request.data
```

It however makes no sense to specify `args=[code]`, since `code` is a dictionary-like structure.

Likely you need some value that corresponds to some key from the `request.data`, so something like:

```
code = request.data['code']
```

Comment: i have done this befor and i recived `MultiValueDictKeyError`.

Comment: @abolfazl81: that is because the key was not in `request.data`, so you made a HTTP request where the key you are looking for is not present.

Comment: @abolfazl81: you can use `print(request.data)` to see what items are in the `request.data`.